# Файловая система android 6

Tags: java, android, io

Приложение сохраняет Bitmap. Вот код их сохранения

```
public Save(Bitmap bitmap,String folder) {
    /*создаем имя файла*/
   editName();

    OutputStream os = null;

    String folderToSave = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()+folder;

    if(folder.equals(Main2Activity.FOLD_TEMP)) {
        Main2Activity.tempPathBitmap.add(folderToSave +"/"+name);
    }
    /*проверяем есть ли папка в которую идет сохраненме
    * если ее нет метод ее создает*/
    createDir(folderToSave);

    File file = new File(folderToSave,name);
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void createDir(String path){
    File file = new File(path);

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

В android-4 и android-5 все работает, а в android-6 не хочет. И да, в манифесте прописал:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В API 23 (Android 6) были введены т.н. *runtime permissions* – теперь для получения некоторых (*dangerous*) разрешений, кроме соответствующей строчки в манифесте требуется еще и запросить эти разрешения в ходе выполнения приложения.

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` относится к категории *dangerous permissions*, соответственно, для записи файлов Вам требуется запросить это разрешение у пользователя в рантайме.

Более подробно: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Я предполагал, что дело в самой версии андроид с ее разрешениями, только не понимал как с этим разобраться из кода. Спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли.