# Не сохраняет аудиопоток

Tags: android

Нашел пример того как сохранять аудиопоток на телефон. Но при нажатии на кнопку открывается прогрессбар и через пару секунд закрывается и не сохраняет. Подскажите пожалуйста где что не так в коде

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadFileAsync().execute("http://cdndl.zaycev.net/126541/6134306/polina_gagarina_-_polina_gagarina_-_obezoruzhena_zaycev.net_%28zaycev.net%29.mp3");
            }
        });
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_file.mp3");
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String progress) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Логи

```
10-27 09:30:43.509 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
10-27 09:31:13.161 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@163138a nm : ru.test.testapp ic=null
10-27 09:31:13.162 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
10-27 09:31:13.163 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=86
10-27 09:31:13.163 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=91
10-27 09:31:18.345 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
10-27 09:34:14.701 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][720,1280] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true -497950720} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
10-27 09:34:14.708 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-27 09:34:14.708 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -497950720}
10-27 09:34:14.709 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ddf8dfb nm : ru.test.testapp ic=null
10-27 09:34:14.709 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
10-27 09:34:14.711 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=88
10-27 09:34:14.711 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=86
10-27 09:34:38.273 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-27 09:34:38.348 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-27 09:34:38.379 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
10-27 09:34:38.384 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=86
10-27 09:34:38.384 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@a73075c[MainActivity] touchMode=true
10-27 09:34:38.386 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-27 09:34:38.387 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-27 09:34:38.387 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
10-27 09:34:38.404 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[18,503][702,824] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -330395648} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
10-27 09:34:38.405 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -330395648} hwInitialized=true
10-27 09:34:38.405 6327-6410/ru.test.testapp D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [812x449]-format:1
10-27 09:34:38.407 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ScrollView:  onsize change changed 
10-27 09:34:38.412 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-27 09:34:38.412 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -330395648}
10-27 09:34:38.425 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(18, 503 - 702, 824) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
10-27 09:34:38.429 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
10-27 09:34:38.572 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp D/ANDRO_ASYNC: Lenght of file: 9127609
10-27 09:34:38.575 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-27 09:34:38.576 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/some_file.mp3 (Permission denied)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:108)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at ru.test.testapp.MainActivity$DownloadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:59)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at ru.test.testapp.MainActivity$DownloadFileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:37)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-27 09:34:38.676 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
10-27 09:34:38.676 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
10-27 09:34:38.676 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-27 09:34:38.676 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
10-27 09:34:38.681 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
10-27 09:34:38.681 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@d1701cf[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-27 09:34:38.689 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=86
10-27 09:34:38.690 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
10-27 09:34:38.690 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -497950720}
10-27 09:34:38.692 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
10-27 09:34:39.929 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 0
10-27 09:34:40.024 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processKey 1
10-27 09:34:40.040 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
10-27 09:34:40.123 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=88
10-27 09:34:40.168 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
10-27 09:34:40.176 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][720,1280] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
10-27 09:34:40.524 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
10-27 09:34:40.524 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/ViewRootImpl@1df63c2[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
10-27 09:34:40.529 6327-6327/ru.test.testapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=71
```

Comment: Для начала добавить в блок `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` и смотреть что пишет в лог

Comment: В какое место именно добавить? В методе onCreate?

Comment: У Вас один catch - в него и добавить `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: В вопрос добавил то что выдало в логах, больше никаких ошибок нет

Comment: обновил логи.. может там что-то будет

Comment: 10-27 09:34:38.572 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp D/ANDRO_ASYNC: Lenght of file: 9127609   вот что в логах

Comment: Вам сюда: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Почитаю вашу ссылку. А в чем проблема в коде?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618975/11515

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/some_file.mp3 (Permission denied) пермишны на чтение external storage включите в манифесте

Comment: Прописал в манифесте     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  все равно не сохраняет. Пишет 10-27 16:29:02.478 4001-4173/ru.test.testapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/some_file.mp3 (Permission denied)

Comment: Даже написал так OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/some_file.mp3"); Не помогло, не сохраняет

Comment: как указать путь к внутренней памяти телефона? может потому что пытаюсь на флешку записать

Comment: Методы контекста дают пути к приватным файлам/папкам приложения, не требующим пермишнов: `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, `openFileOutput()` etc...